# How to restrict access to my subversion server (i.e. svnserve) by IP address, so only my IP can checkout, commit, etc.?

Tags: security, svn, whitelist

I'm using Ubuntu and I have my subversion server running as you can see below:

```
root     31422     1  0 06:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/svnserve -d -r /var/svn/repos --log-file=/var/log/svnserve.log
```

I want to whitelist my subversion server, in other words, I want to allow only my IP address to checkout, commit, log, etc. Does svnserve support that?

**NOTE:** I'm not using Apache to access my subversion

Answer (score 1):

Seems a perfect situation for an ip-based firewall rule? So you would only accept connections to the port that svnserve is listening to (3690 by default), from an individual IP? Depending on the platform your svn server is, the needed steps may vary.